# Linear Algebra Eigenvector Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $v_1$ be an eigenvector of an $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_1$, and let $v_2, v_3$ be two linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_2$. Assume $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$. Show that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent.

I know this should be pretty easy, but I'm just not getting it...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose $v_1=c_2v_2+c_3v_3$. Now multiply both sides by $A$.

Comment: @Jared  $\lambda_2(c_2v_2+c_3v_3)=\lambda_2v_1$ by the assumption and also $\lambda_2(c_2v_2+c_3v_3)=\lambda_1v_1$ because of the matrix multiplication...